# shibboleth idp get user attributes

Tags: java, shibboleth

I am making a plugin (in JAVA) for shibboleth idp. In the plugin, I need to get the user's attributes if the user is authenticated. I use a Filter (pattern /profile/*) to process the request, but none of the user attributes is stored in the request's attributes or header, how could I retrieve the user's attributes in Java code if the user is authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open your **AJP port** in your application server. Attributes will be sent out to only those pages where AJP is enables. (you may want to add `attributePrefix="AJP_"` to your conf file.)

You need to add following to your proxy server (considering AJP port is open on 8009)

ProxyPass /profile/* ajp://localhost:8009/profile/*

Even if this is done, shibboleth parameters won't display directly under `parameters.keySet()`. But if you do `parameters.get(key)` then it will return some value sent by shib.

Above behaviour may vary for different servers; i.e. you may need to get values by `parameters.get("AJP_"+key)`. P.S. check in both header and request object.

Comment: The AJP port is on the sp side as far as I can see, and in the sp url/Shibboleth.sso/Session I can see the attributes. Does the AJP port setting help to get the attributes in the JAVA on idp side?